# How often to check external storage availability android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I was reading the documentation for performing write operation to external storage in android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). I was wondering if I should only check once when the program is opened or if I should check before any time I wish to write.

Comment: I find that it is not really necessary to check for availability as you'll just get `IOException` in case if it is not available. And at this point you might want to check what went wrong and take according actions (like show appropriate error message to the user).

Comment: You should once or twice maybe.. but checking the availability each time you wana write seems vague.. since its highly unlikely someone would un mount the SD card while your app is open. Since many sd card slots of android devices are besides the battery.

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev This seems logical. Can anyone else attest to the reliability of this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to check when ever you are performing the write operations. Before performing the write operations once check the availability of the storage.